# openldap: how to implement password policies?

Tags: password, openldap, password-policy

I would like to implement password policies for all openldap users.

there are 2 things i would like to do:

1. password aging (users should be forced to change their passwords at least every 90 days)
2. password complexity ( users must have a password minimal length of 8chars including at least 1 number, 1 alpha and 1 special )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [12.10. Password Policies from the OpenLDAP manual.](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Password%20Policies)

The second part will probably require some coding but the overlay works and any client that listens to what OpenLDAP tells it will warn about expiring passwords.

I'd also recommend a password history, strictly speaking your requirements don't force a user to change from one password to another, but only from the old password to the new (which could be the same regarding your requirements)

Comment: Will this work for Windows Clients?